# MVC C# Selected Item is set to null while navigating from one viewmodel to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, telerik, radgridview

Hi i have a radgrid on one page and i am selecting an item and sending that item to another page, the item is getting selected but the problem is whenever the new view model is made it initializes my selected item value to null in first view model.

xaml.cs

```
<telerik:RadGridView  Loaded="ItemGrid_Loaded" SelectionMode="Single" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" SelectionChanged="grdArticles_SelectionChanged" x:Name="grdArticles" 
                                                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem" 
                                                              IsReadOnly="True"
                                                               ItemsSource="{Binding ListArticles, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                              ShowColumnHeaders="False" Height="150" Width="400" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" >
                                            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Code}"                                                   
                                                    IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"                                                   
                                                    IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                                <!--<telerik:GridViewColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <telerik:RadButton Content="?" Width="10"/>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </telerik:GridViewColumn>-->
                                            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

my view model

```
     public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            { _selectedItem=value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Element1");

OnPropertyChanged("Element1");
}
}
```

My selectedItem is set to null once i move to another page

Answer (score 0):

Typo ? Replace :

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem"
```

With

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```